# How do I change the default front page?

Tags: 7, uri

How do I change the URL present under Home » Administration » Configuration » System in my Drupal site?
I want to get rid of the stuff circled in red, but it only seems that I can add different pages only in the blank input box next to it.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It is because you run Drupal in local; if you uploaded your site to a valid domain or set a [virtual host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting), you get rid of it.

You can set your virtual Host following [How to Add Virtual Directory Alias on Apache Xampp](http://el.web.id/how-to-add-virtual-directory-alias-on-apache-xampp-165). You could also use [Acquia Desktop dev2](https://docs.acquia.com/dev-desktop2) which handles virtual hosts by itself.

Comment: Thanks - I am using cPanel, I obviously missed out some setting on there as that is my server. Do you know how to fix that on cPanel?